# How can i manage featured option if new article is create then old featured is expired and it show in without featured list?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i have two type of list's one is with featured boolean second is without featured. How can i manage featured option if new article is create then old featured is get expired and it's show in without featured list? [example is here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDG6y.png)

views.py

```
articles = Article.status_objects.filter(featured=True)[:1]

articleslist = Article.status_objects.all().exclude(featured=True)[:2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override you save method of your models.py

add this code to you models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    featured=models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.featured==True:
            Article.objects.filter(featured=True).update(featured=False)
            self.featured=True
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```